# How to access current location using my android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, currentlocation, google-location-services

I'm trying to access my current location using this sample code ( I have already configure my API key):

MapActivity:

```
public class MapsActivityCurrentPlace extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
                GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MapsActivityCurrentPlace.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private CameraPosition mCameraPosition;

    // The entry point to Google Play services, used by the Places API and Fused Location Provider.
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // A default location (Sydney, Australia) and default zoom to use when location permission is
    // not granted.
    private final LatLng mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085);
    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;

    // The geographical location where the device is currently located. That is, the last-known
    // location retrieved by the Fused Location Provider.
    private Location mLastKnownLocation;

    // Keys for storing activity state.
    private static final String KEY_CAMERA_POSITION = "camera_position";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";

    // Used for selecting the current place.
    private final int mMaxEntries = 5;
    private String[] mLikelyPlaceNames = new String[mMaxEntries];
    private String[] mLikelyPlaceAddresses = new String[mMaxEntries];
    private String[] mLikelyPlaceAttributions = new String[mMaxEntries];
    private LatLng[] mLikelyPlaceLatLngs = new LatLng[mMaxEntries];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }

        // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Build the Play services client for use by the Fused Location Provider and the Places API.
        // Use the addApi() method to request the Google Places API and the Fused Location Provider.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                        this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    /**
     * Saves the state of the map when the activity is paused.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (mMap != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, mMap.getCameraPosition());
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, mLastKnownLocation);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Builds the map when the Google Play services client is successfully connected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // Build the map.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Handles failure to connect to the Google Play services client.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the reference doc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might
        // be returned in onConnectionFailed.
        Log.d(TAG, "Play services connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    /**
     * Handles suspension of the connection to the Google Play services client.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Play services connection suspended");
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the options menu.
     * @param menu The options menu.
     * @return Boolean.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.current_place_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handles a click on the menu option to get a place.
     * @param item The menu item to handle.
     * @return Boolean.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.option_get_place) {
            showCurrentPlace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map when it's available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;

        // Use a custom info window adapter to handle multiple lines of text in the
        // info window contents.
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            // Return null here, so that getInfoContents() is called next.
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Inflate the layouts for the info window, title and snippet.
                View infoWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents,
                        (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.map), false);

                TextView title = ((TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title));
                title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                TextView snippet = ((TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                return infoWindow;
            }
        });

        // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
        updateLocationUI();

        // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
        getDeviceLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current location of the device, and positions the map's camera.
     */
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
         * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
         * onRequestPermissionsResult.
         */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         */
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mLastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        }

        // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
        if (mCameraPosition != null) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(mCameraPosition));
        } else if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                            mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the result of the request for location permissions.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }

    /**
     * Prompts the user to select the current place from a list of likely places, and shows the
     * current place on the map - provided the user has granted location permission.
     */
    private void showCurrentPlace() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            // Get the likely places - that is, the businesses and other points of interest that
            // are the best match for the device's current location.
            @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
            PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                    .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                    int i = 0;
                    mLikelyPlaceNames = new String[mMaxEntries];
                    mLikelyPlaceAddresses = new String[mMaxEntries];
                    mLikelyPlaceAttributions = new String[mMaxEntries];
                    mLikelyPlaceLatLngs = new LatLng[mMaxEntries];
                    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                        // Build a list of likely places to show the user. Max 5.
                        mLikelyPlaceNames[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName();
                        mLikelyPlaceAddresses[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress();
                        mLikelyPlaceAttributions[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                                .getAttributions();
                        mLikelyPlaceLatLngs[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng();

                        i++;
                        if (i > (mMaxEntries - 1)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // Release the place likelihood buffer, to avoid memory leaks.
                    likelyPlaces.release();

                    // Show a dialog offering the user the list of likely places, and add a
                    // marker at the selected place.
                    openPlacesDialog();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Add a default marker, because the user hasn't selected a place.
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(getString(R.string.default_info_title))
                    .position(mDefaultLocation)
                    .snippet(getString(R.string.default_info_snippet)));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form allowing the user to select a place from a list of likely places.
     */
    private void openPlacesDialog() {
        // Ask the user to choose the place where they are now.
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener =
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // The "which" argument contains the position of the selected item.
                        LatLng markerLatLng = mLikelyPlaceLatLngs[which];
                        String markerSnippet = mLikelyPlaceAddresses[which];
                        if (mLikelyPlaceAttributions[which] != null) {
                            markerSnippet = markerSnippet + "\n" + mLikelyPlaceAttributions[which];
                        }
                        // Add a marker for the selected place, with an info window
                        // showing information about that place.
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .title(mLikelyPlaceNames[which])
                                .position(markerLatLng)
                                .snippet(markerSnippet));

                        // Position the map's camera at the location of the marker.
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(markerLatLng,
                                DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                    }
                };

        // Display the dialog.
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.pick_place)
                .setItems(mLikelyPlaceNames, listener)
                .show();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the map's UI settings based on whether the user has granted location permission.
     */
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
         * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
         * onRequestPermissionsResult.
         */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            mLastKnownLocation = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packagename">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <permission
        android:name="package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.envent_pc03.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap.MapsActivityCurrentPlace"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My problem is that it is not getting current location untill device preinstalled google map not getting permission like this:
[image]

**How to get above permission through my app intead of preinstalled google map and get current location, without use of preinstalled google map.**

Comment: so let me know if you reach some thing new.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap, PID: 21429
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap.MapsActivityCurrentPlace cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
                      at com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap.MapsActivityCurrentPlace.onConnected(MapsActivityCurrentPlace.java:137)

Comment: LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);

Comment: Error due to above line@IbrahimBaz

Comment: check answer update